# compilation error on dart/flutter with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have 2 classes
A:
with the function

```
  static Future<bool> setToken(String? value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString(_kToken, value);
  }
```

and B which is called by A

```
  Future<bool> setString(String key, **String? value**) =>
      _setValue('String', key, value);
```

in A, the parameter 'value' is underlined and I have a compilation error  on

```
prefs.setString('token', value);
```

*The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'*.

However I writed String**?** value on setString in B class ...?

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

`setString` required non-nullable string data,

```dart
  Future<bool> setString(String key, String value) =>
      _setValue('String', key, value);
```

you can avoid putting data while it is null.

```dart
Future<bool> setToken(String? value) async {
  if (value == null) return false;

  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.setString("_kToken", value);
}
```

Comment: I used your if (value == null) return false; Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: You can find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `?` because `setString` expects a non-null value.

```
  static Future<bool> setToken(String value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString(_kToken, value);
  }
```